# Problema para sumar señales en VHDL

Tags: embebido, vhdl

Estaba trabajando en una práctica que me encargaron en la escuela, en VHDL, el entorno es el ISE 14.7 y el kit es un Spartan 3E.

La práctica se trata de un pequeño pseudo-procesador. De hecho, está casi funcionando. En teoría, lo que debería hacer sería:

- tomará un valor de una memoria (será simulada por los 4 switches de la FPGA)
- guardarlo en una variable A
- tomar otro valor de la misma memoria (de nuevo los switches)
- guardarlo en una variable B
- sumarlos
- mostrar en 2 displays el resultado (máximo 30)
- tomar de nuevo un valor y ponerlo en A
- tomar otro valor y ponerlo en B
- restar A-B
- mostrarlo en los displays (sólo módulo, no signo)

Cuando lo probé, solucioné el rebote con la primera parte. Ésta hace un preescaler y a la vez funciona como filtro. La parte del final actúa como un multiplexor (aclaro en ninguno de los dos casos está el problema).

El problema radica en el *process* del procesador central. Éste tiene en lista de sensibilidad T y cada vez que se da un clic avanza, funciona todo bien, muestra los valores y avanza cada vez que se da el clic al botón llamado timer. El problema es que al llegar a la suma o resta de los valores almacenados en las variables A y B no da un resultado correcto, simplemente no almacena el valor.

---

Éste es el fragmento que me da problemas. Pareciera que cada vez que T se incrementa, los valores de A y B, si es que ya se capturaron, se resetean, de modo que la operación nunca se lleva a cabo correctamente.

Por su parte, val es una señal que se manda a dos displays para multiplexar. Esta parte funciona correctamente, mi problema es que cada que cambio de posición en los `If` con "T" los valores de las variables A y B no se mantienen.

```
PROCESS(T)
    variable A:    std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
    variable B:    std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
    variable C:    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN  --  BLOQUE #2

IF T="00000" THEN--0
    X0<="00000011"; 
END IF;

IF T="00001" THEN--1
    IF MEM="0001" THEN 
       VAL<="00001";
    ELSE
       VAL<="11111";
    END IF;
    X0<="00000110";
END IF;
IF T="00010" THEN--2
    X0<="00011010";
END IF;

IF T="00011" THEN--3
    X0<="00000011";
END IF;

IF T="00100" THEN--4
    VAL<=('0'& MEM);--se carga el primer valor
    X0<="00000110";
END IF;

IF T="00101" THEN--5
    A:=MEM;
    VAL<=('0' & A);
    X0<="00110010";
END IF;

IF T="00110" THEN--6
    --X0<="01010010";
    X0<="00000011";
END IF;

IF T="00111" THEN--7
    B:=MEM;
    VAL<=('0' & B);
    X0<="00000110";
END IF;

IF T="01000" THEN--8
    X0<="01010010";
END IF;

IF T="01001" THEN--9
   C:=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(UNSIGNED(A)+UNSIGNED(B));
   VAL<=(C);--se muestra el resultado
    X0<="10000010";
END IF;

IF T="01010" THEN--10
    X0<="00000011";
END IF;

IF T="01011" THEN--11
    IF MEM="0001" THEN 
       VAL<="00010";
    ELSE
       VAL<="11111";
    END IF;
    X0<="00000110";
END IF;

IF T="01100" THEN--12
    X0<="00011010";
END IF;

IF T="01101" THEN--13
    X0<="00000011";
END IF;

IF T="01110" THEN--14
    VAL<=('0' & MEM);--se muestra el primer valor
    X0<="00000110";
END IF;

IF T="01111" THEN--15
    A:=MEM;
    VAL<=('0' & MEM);
    X0<="00110010";
END IF;

IF T="10000" THEN--16
    X0<="00000011";
END IF;

IF T="10001" THEN--17
    VAL<=('0' & MEM);--se muestra el segundo valor
    X0<="00000110";
END IF;

IF T="10010" THEN--18
    B:=MEM;
    VAL<=('0' & B);
    X0<="01010010";
END IF;

IF T="10011" THEN--19
   C:=STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(UNSIGNED(A)-UNSIGNED(B));--se muestra la operacion
    VAL<=(C);
    X0<="00000000";
END IF;

if T>"10011" then
   X0<="00000000";
end if;

END PROCESS;
```